# Custom View inside Custom View

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom View, which extends RelativeLayout.
This Relative Layout should consist of Rectangles which extends View, and this Rectangles should be painted by a bitmap and have a TextView in it..

But i cant add this Rectangles to the RelativeLayout so that they are below of each other.. it seems that the LayoutParams do not work.. Can you help me please?

Custom View extends RelativeLayout

```
public class DrawView extends RelativeLayout {
    private Context context;

    public DrawView(Context context, ArrayList<String> dragFieldText, ArrayList<String> targetFieldText, int height, int width) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        Rectangle.count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < targetFieldText.size(); i++) {

            Rectangle targetRectangle = new Rectangle(context);         
            this.addView(targetRectangle);
        }

        Rectangle tmpRect = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < dragFieldText.size(); i++) {

            Rectangle dragRectangle = new Rectangle(context);

            if(tmpRect != null){
                tmpRect.setId(i);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tmpRect.getId());
                dragRectangle.setLayoutParams(lp);          
            } 

            this.addView(dragRectangle);        
            tmpRect = dragRectangle;

        }       

    }

@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
```

Rectangle extends View

```
public class Rectangle extends View{

    public Rectangle(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(getSomeBitmapImg(), new Matrix(), null);


    }
```

Comment: Try not using FILL_PARENT FILL_PARENT inside the layout params.